# Symfony2: change APC to xcache

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, apc, xcache

Because a Bug in APC, i had to use another Cache-Drive. I removed APC and installed xcache. config.php says *Your configuration looks good to run Symfony*.

I got the following error on request:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to use ApcClassLoader as APC is not enabled.' in /var/.../app/bootstrap.php.cache:1039
Stack trace:
#0 /var/.../web/app.php(11): Symfony\\Component\\ClassLoader\\ApcClassLoader->__construct('sf2', Object(Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader))
#1 {main}
thrown in /var/...app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 1039
```

How do I tell Symfony to use xcache instead of APC?

Comment: Problem fixed: changed web/app.php to use xcache

Comment: Other PHP-Projects throw an Segmentation Fault when APC is installed

Comment: How exactly did you changed web/app.php to use xcache? Wouldn't you mean ./autoload.php? And once that is clarified, what exactly was the change in the file? is it enough with 'use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\XCacheClassLoader' instead of use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

had the same problem, this is how i did it:

In line 12 replace

```
$loader = new ApcClassLoader('sf2', $loader);
```

with

```
$loader = new XcacheClassLoader('sf2', $loader);
```

(and define correct use statement)

Answer (score 0):

after replace `$loader = new ApcClassLoader('tcs_beta_prod', $loader);` to
`$loader = new XcacheClassLoader('tcs_beta_prod', $loader);` and add `use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\XcacheClassLoader;` i have this bug `Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\XcacheClassLoader' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\edt\web\app.php on line 11`. 
Here is my app.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\XcacheClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

// Use APC for autoloading to improve performance
// Change 'sf2' by the prefix you want in order to prevent key conflict with another application

$loader = new XcacheClassLoader('tcs_beta_prod', $loader);
$loader->register(true);


require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
Request::setTrustedProxies(array($request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR'))); // per suggestion from Farid / Patrick to deal with ELB proxying
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the use statement for XCache:

```
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\XcacheClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\XcacheClassLoader;
```